# How to be able to plot Matrix and the mean of matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

Heiii,,

If I have Matrix

```
 A= n*m 
 and 

 average=mean(A).
```

How I can possible to plot all the value in matrix (there will be n points) and a Average at the same figure in Matlab??

Anyone has the solution??

### ---------------------

### QUESTION

---

I want to plot my data for PCA.

For ex/ I have 100*50 matrix.

Im now sure, but may be we can consider the column as the feature (feature = 50). And for the row, I may be the training data.

So we have 100 training data/image. And I also have mean from my initial matrix.

So, now, Im going to plot each data(100) for every feature (50) and also the mean at the same figure.

Here is the example of figure I want to [plot](http://www.google.fr/imgres?sa=X&espvd=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=qY6rbx4QTw9S_M%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aanda.org%2Farticles%2Faa%2Ffull%2F2007%2F07%2Faa6548-06%2Faa6548-06.fig.html&docid=zpg-ZQRMYtuXaM&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aanda.org%2Farticles%2Faa%2Ffull%2F2007%2F07%2Faa6548-06%2Fimg7.gif&w=452&h=422&ei=TGcCU8DmDePe7AbEvoHIAg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=1479&page=2&start=17&ndsp=21&ved=0CJABEK0DMBM)..

Can u please help me solve this Master ;)

Comment: Which size does the matrix have? Is it n x m, or does it have n points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer of mine assumes that you have a matrix of `nxm`. Then you can use 3-D scatter-plot as follows:

```
%creating all combinations of x and y coordinates
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:size(A,2),1:size(A,1));
x=x(:);
y=y(:);

%plotting values of A such that X-Y axis represent the column and row coordinates of A
%respectively. Z-axis represents the value at that coordinate.
scatter3(x,y,A(:),30,'rx');

%plotting the mean at the center of the coordinate system
hold on;scatter3(mean([1:size(A,2)]),mean([1:size(A,1)]),mean2(A),60,'go','filled');
```

Comment: Heyy,, this is my input A=[12 3 4; 5 6 7; 4 3 2]; and mean=mean(A);. and all the rest are same as what u told,, but I got this error "Error using scatter3 (line 68)
X, Y and Z must be vectors of the same length."

Comment: Acctually not!! I need to plot my M*N matrix in 2D to make it clear!! Can u please help me to be able to plot in 2D?? I really appriciate ur help if u can help me to do that

Comment: @user3303896 You have 3 values-> (row,column) pair and then the value at that point. To be able to plot in 2-D, you have to plot only two values out of three OR use a different kind of plot (for example, see the answer by @LuisMendo). Which option you want to take?

Answer (score 0):

If it's meaningful to plot each row of `A` with a different curve (you don't specify how you want to plot `A`):

```
plot(A.') %'// plot(X) plots the *columns* of X
hold on
plot(mean(A),'k--') %// plot the mean of (the rows of) A
```

[image]

Comment: If A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 2 3]; How many points should be plotted?

Comment: In that case my code would plot _four_ coloured curves, one for each row if `A`. However, for those values two of the curves coincide

Comment: Why there is a transpose?? Because u want to plot each column?

Comment: I update my question.. there is a part in bottom which I explain more clearly my question. And I also provide an example image which I want to plot my data same as that image. I cannot write in comment because it's too long... I need ur help Master.. Its really URGETNT!!! Im waiting for ur answer ;)

Comment: There is a transpose to plot each _row_. Remove the transpose to plot each column

Comment: I update my question!! Please check it,, under QUESTION

Comment: I saw it, but sorry, I don't understand what you want

Comment: I just want to do plotting of all my matrix's data same as what is showed at that image. The point will be presented as a dot. The COLUMN data will be as X in the coordinate and the ROW will be as Y in the coorinate. U can ignore the lines in that image...